# Ayuda con este ejercicio en java

Tags: java

Estoy practicando algoritmia en java, exactamente las condicionales if-else, y me piden hacer este ejercicio:

16. Después de ingresar 4 notas, obtener el promedio de las 3 mejores notas y el mensaje aprobado si
    el promedio es mayor o iguala 11, caso contrario, desaprobado

Y llevo esto pero no me ejecuta como debe ser
Me ejecuta algo asi

```
Ingrese la primer nota: 5
Ingrese la segunda nota: 4
Ingrese la tercera nota: 3
Ingrese la cuarta nota: 2

DESAPROBADO

Process finished with exit code 0
```

El código es:

```
int nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, prom;
    String calificacion = "";

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ingrese la primer nota: ");
    nota1 = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la segunda nota: ");
    nota2 = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la tercera nota: ");
    nota3 = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la cuarta nota: ");
    nota4 = teclado.nextInt();

    if (nota1 <= nota2 && nota1 <= nota3 && nota1 <= nota4) {
        prom = nota2 + nota3 + nota4 / 3;
    } else {
        if (nota2 <= nota1 && nota2 <= nota3 && nota2 <= nota4){
            prom = nota1 + nota3 + nota4 / 3;
        } else {
            if (nota3 <= nota1 && nota3 <= nota2 && nota3 <= nota4){
                prom = nota1 + nota2 + nota4 / 3;
            } else {
                prom = nota1 + nota2 + nota3 / 3;
            }
        }
    }

    if (prom >= 11){
        calificacion = "APROBADO";
    } else {
        calificacion = "DESAPROBADO";
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(calificacion);

}
```

Les agradezco si me podrían orientar a como realizar este ejercicio de la forma correcta.
Saludos

Comment: Cada suma debes ponerla entre parentesis, por ejemplo: (nota1 + nota2 + nota4) / 3 Puedes optimizar tu codigo para hacerlo con un ciclo for de 4 iteraciones para ingresar las notas. El caso de prueba que mencionas te da promedio 4, por ende esta bien que de desaprobado, pero igualmente tienes ese problema de separacion de terminos.

Comment: Gracias bro si no me habia fijado en eso , lo hice con numeros mas grandes y si me da tal cual. Igual gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 1):

yo veo varias cosas:

1. Si quieres que te salga aprobado, y el promedio para esto es mayor a 11, entonces debes usar números más grandes que los que usas. p.e. 10, 11, 12 o algo así.
2. Cuando tienes lo siguiente:

```
    prom = nota1 + nota2 + nota3 / 3;
```

Estás cometiendo un error, pues el resultado será (nota3/3) + (nota1 + nota2). Revisa el tema de precedencia de oparadores. Esto lo solucionas con un parentesis así:

```
    prom = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos *(Mi sugerencia, muy poco sé de java)***

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

1. declarar un `array` de `int`s.
2. En 1 sola variable leer del teclado el `int` y ese valor agregarlo al `array`.
3. Leídos los **N** valores y con estos en el [array ordenarlos](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm).
4. Obtienes los [últimos 3 elementos](https://www.techiedelight.com/get-subarray-array-specified-indexes-java/).
5. Haces la sumatoria.
6. Realizas la división (guardando su resultado en una variable).
7. Realizas la comprobación.

**Algo como (es idea)***

```
/* Declarar función donde corresponda a tu estructura */
public int[] addX(int n, int arr[], int x) 
{ 
   /* https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-an-element-to-an-array-in-java/ */
   int i; 
  
   // create a new array of size n+1 
   int newarr[] = new int[n + 1]; 
  
   // insert the elements from 
   // the old array into the new array 
   // insert all elements till n 
   // then insert x at n+1 
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      newarr[i] = arr[i]; 
  
   newarr[n] = x; 
  
   return newarr; 
} 
/* Declarar función donde corresponda a tu estructura */


/* A CONTINUACIÓN TU CÓDIGO QUE PROPORCIONASTE "MODIFICADO" */
   int[] Calificaciones={};
   int[] SumarParaPromedio={};
   int promediarCon =3; // Total de elementos a incluir
   
   int calificacion, prom=0;
   String calificacion = "";

   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Ingrese la primer nota: ");
   calificacion= teclado.nextInt();
   Calificaciones=addX(Calificaciones.length, Calificaciones, calificacion);
   System.out.print("Ingrese la segunda nota: ");
   calificacion= teclado.nextInt();
   Calificaciones=addX(Calificaciones.length, Calificaciones, calificacion);
   System.out.print("Ingrese la tercera nota: ");
   calificacion= teclado.nextInt();
   Calificaciones=addX(Calificaciones.length, Calificaciones, calificacion);
   System.out.print("Ingrese la cuarta nota: ");
   calificacion= teclado.nextInt();
   Calificaciones=addX(Calificaciones.length, Calificaciones, calificacion);

   Arrays.sort(Calificaciones);

   // Estraemos los ultimos "promediarCon"
   int posicion=Calificaciones.lenght-promediarCon;
   while(posicion<Calificaciones.length){
      SumarParaPromedio=addX(SumarParaPromedio.length, SumarParaPromedio, Calificaciones[posicion]);
      posicion++;
   }
   // Realizamos la sumatoria
   for (int number : SumarParaPromedio) {
         prom+=number;
   }

   prom=prom/promediarCon;

   if (prom >= 11){
       calificacion = "APROBADO";
   } else {
       calificacion = "DESAPROBADO";
   }

   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println(calificacion);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

quizá simplificando un poco con Stream resulte ser hasta mas fácil de leer

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] notas = new int[4];
        double promedio = 0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Ingresamos las 4 notas
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la nota: " + i + ": ");
            notas[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        //Obtenemos el promedio con Average() excluyendo el min de los 4 ingresados
        promedio = Arrays.stream(notas).filter(x -> x != Arrays.stream(notas).min().getAsInt()).mapToDouble(d -> d).average().orElse(0.0);

        if (promedio >= 11) {
            System.out.println("APROBADO");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DESAPROBADO");
        }

        System.out.println(promedio);
    }
}
```

Basicamente lo que hice fue obtener le promedio de los numeros ingresados excluyendo la nota mas baja.

OutPut:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizá te sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!